# How to search for consecutive values in mySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a search in MySql but cant figure out how to set up the query. I know my DB set up is a little disorganized but Im stuck with it now. Any way I want to search the attrValue column and look for the unique string and after I find it I want to display it along with the 10 consecutive (following) results.
Is this even possible in my case?

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT attrName, attrValue
FROM def_servpath_0001_weatherstation
JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM def_servpath_0001_weatherstation
WHERE attrValue = '8:0:0,1.9.2015'
)t
LIMIT 11
```

But I had no luck with it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

**EDIT 1** I am providing the dump for the table:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.9
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Sep 01, 2015 at 10:07 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.73
-- PHP Version: 5.3.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `def_serv`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `def_servpath_0001_weatherstation`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `def_servpath_0001_weatherstation` (
  `recvTimeTs` mediumtext,
  `recvTime` text,
  `entityId` text,
  `entityType` text,
  `attrName` text,
  `attrType` text,
  `attrValue` text,
  `attrMd` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `def_servpath_0001_weatherstation`
--



INSERT INTO `def_servpath_0001_weatherstation` (`recvTimeTs`, `recvTime`, `entityId`, `entityType`, `attrName`, `attrType`, `attrValue`, `attrMd`) VALUES
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '6:30:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '18.799', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '91.0', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.01', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '270', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '17.181', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.683', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '17.181', '[]'),
('1441083706', '2015-09-01T07:01:46.104', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '6.552', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '6:45:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '18.799', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '91.0', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '270', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '17.898', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.683', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '17.898', '[]'),
('1441083713', '2015-09-01T07:01:53.549', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '6.591', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '7:0:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '19.400', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '91.0', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '270', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '18.488', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.683', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '18.488', '[]'),
('1441083720', '2015-09-01T07:02:00.951', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '6.640', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '7:15:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '19.400', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '91.0', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.59', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '236', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '18.801', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.386', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '18.801', '[]'),
('1441087323', '2015-09-01T08:02:03.349', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '6.689', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '7:30:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '20.0', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '90.0', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.35', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '290', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '18.894', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.683', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '18.894', '[]'),
('1441087330', '2015-09-01T08:02:10.383', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '6.757', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '7:45:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '20.5', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '90.0', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.37', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '322', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '19.298', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.683', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '19.298', '[]'),
('1441087338', '2015-09-01T08:02:18.889', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '6.865', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '8:0:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '21.099', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '88.0', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.35', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '290', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '19.391', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.386', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '19.391', '[]'),
('1441087346', '2015-09-01T08:02:26.037', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '6.923', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '8:15:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '21.599', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '85.0', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.52', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '282', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '19.548', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.386', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '19.548', '[]'),
('1441090890', '2015-09-01T09:01:30.186', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '6.962', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '8:30:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '22.200', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '84.0', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.98', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '58', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '19.796', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.386', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '19.796', '[]'),
('1441090898', '2015-09-01T09:01:38.072', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '7.011', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '8:45:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '23.299', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '80.0', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.27', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '242', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '19.796', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.386', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '19.796', '[]'),
('1441090905', '2015-09-01T09:01:45.32', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '7.118', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '9:0:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '24.400', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '77.0', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.22', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '270', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '20.138', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.386', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '20.138', '[]'),
('1441090913', '2015-09-01T09:01:53.36', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '7.060', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'time', 'datetime', '9:15:0,1.9.2015', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'at', 'double', '25.5', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ah', 'double', '68.0', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'ws', 'double', '0.65', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'wd', 'int', '280', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'pp', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sr', 'double', '20.170', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sm1', 'double', '24.386', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'lw1', 'double', '0.0', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'sp', 'double', '20.170', '[]'),
('1441094510', '2015-09-01T10:01:50.44', '0001', 'WeatherStation', 'bt', 'double', '7.050', '[]');
```

Comment: "The next 10 rows" requires an order; how are the rows to be ordered? The timestamp of all rows in the set is the same. If you don't define and order, "the next 10 rows" is almost meaningless and the results are undefined.

Comment: could it be that you simply want all rows that have the same timestamp as the one in your original result?

Comment: the layout is always going to be the same, and the values after time constantly show in the same order (at, ah, ws... sp, bt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT attrName, attrValue
FROM def_servpath_0001_weatherstation
WHERE attrValue = '8:0:0,1.9.2015'

UNION 

SELECT a.attrName, a.attrValue
FROM def_servpath_0001_weatherstation a
JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM def_servpath_0001_weatherstation
WHERE attrValue = '8:0:0,1.9.2015'
)b ON a.recvTimeTs=b.recvTimeTs AND a.attrValue <>'8:0:0,1.9.2015'
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Looks promising but I cant figure out why I get the error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT attrName, attrValue FROM def_servpath_0001_weatherstation a JOIN ( SEL' at line 9`

Comment: I see but I am beginning to think that the two guys in the first comments are right. I now get the error: `Column 'attrName' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Updated again (sorry). About the other comments, if you have more than 10 consecutive record you should decide how to order them because limit 10 only returns the first 10

Comment: Its my fault I havent provided a dump for the table. Your query returns no errors now, but it only gets me one record which is `time
8:0:0,1.9.2015`

Comment: Updated again, sorry for all the clumsy mistakes

Comment: That's it! thanks, and again it was my mistake for not sending the dump.